# Duplicated Items in My Listview with each going to activity

Tags: android, listview

I read a lot about duplicating  items but there wasn't solution for me ,
still 4 days search too with no answer work with me 
i wish to find answer please people

**This is class adapter that is in activity class**

```
private class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public TestAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_row_workout, R.id.text_title , titles);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row=convertView;
        MyHolderview_BA holderview=null;
        if (row==null){

            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_row_workout , parent , false);
            holderview = new MyHolderview_BA(row);

            row.setTag(holderview);
        }else{
            holderview = (MyHolderview_BA) row.getTag();
        }

        holderview.tv_title.setText(titles[position]);
        holderview.tv_desc.setText(  desc[position] );

        return row;
    }
} 


class MyHolderview_BA{
    TextView tv_title,tv_desc;
    MyHolderview_BA(View row){
        tv_title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        tv_desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_desc);
    }
}

//**strong text**
```

**here is titles and desc arrays from an another intent**

```
public class MyDay_Program extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
TextView address_TV;

String Address="";
String titles[];
String desc[];

String day;

//    MyBAseAdapter myBAseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_day__program);

    Address= getIntent().getExtras().getString("Address");
    titles = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(StaticsVariables.title);
    desc =  getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(StaticsVariables.Desc);

    day = getIntent().getExtras().getString("day");

    address_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_myday_program);
    address_TV.setText("Address");

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myday_program_listview);

    //myBAseAdapter = new MyBAseAdapter();

    listView.setAdapter( new TestAdapter(this) );
    //myBAseAdapter.Cleardata();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int positin, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MyDay_Program.this , StartWorkout.class);

            intent.putExtra( StaticsVariables.title , titles[positin]   );
            intent.putExtra( StaticsVariables.Desc  , desc[positin]   );
            intent.putExtra( StaticsVariables.image , R.drawable.fitness );

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

this is The Intent that Go Activity and put data into
myDataBase.Select_All_DAY(programs[position]) RETRIEVE data table from DATABASE SQLITE 
titles and desc are arraylists and Address is String
.
.
.

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyDay_Program.class);

```
            MyDataBase myDataBase = new MyDataBase(getActivity());
            Cursor cursor = myDataBase.Select_All_DAY(programs[position]);
            //Log.d("testdb",programs[position]);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {  //if day contain Workouts

                do {

                    titles.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                    desc.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc")));
                    //images.add( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex("image") ) );
                    Log.d("testdb", titles.get(0) + " : " + desc.get(0));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                cursor.close();

                String[] Mytitles = titles.toArray(new String[titles.size()]);
                String[] Mydesc = desc.toArray(new String[desc.size()]);

                intent.putExtra("Address", programs[position]);
                intent.putExtra(StaticsVariables.title, Mytitles);
                intent.putExtra(StaticsVariables.Desc, Mydesc);


                //intent.putExtra("day", programs[position]);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Post the code of the previous Activity, where you put the data into the Intent.

Comment: I edited the code and added the code of the intent that put data into it  , please help me

Comment: please people , can anyone help me please :(